# Pandas : Adding new column depending on a group aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie with Pandas data frame and I need some help.

Let's say that I have a DataFrame df :

```
>>print(df)
        ID    Score       
0       AA      100       
1       AA       10        
2       BB       50 
3       BB      -20
4       BB        0
5       AA      200
```

And I want to add a new column with value = 1. If it is the lowest score for the ID, and 0 else :

```
>> print(df_out)
        ID    Score  IsLowestScoreID     
0       AA      100                0
1       AA       10                1
2       BB       50                0
3       BB      -20                1
4       BB        0                0
5       AA      200                0
```

What is the correct way to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) column `Score` with `Series` created by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `min`, then cast mask to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df['IsLowestScoreID'] = df['Score'].eq(df.groupby('ID')['Score'].transform('min')).astype(int)
print (df)
   ID  Score  IsLowestScoreID
0  AA    100                0
1  AA     10                1
2  BB     50                0
3  BB    -20                1
4  BB      0                0
5  AA    200                0
```

Alternative is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for specify values by mask:

```
mask = df['Score'].eq(df.groupby('ID')['Score'].transform('min'))
df['IsLowestScoreID'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['Score'].transform('min'))
0    10
1    10
2   -20
3   -20
4   -20
5    10
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it. So it is basically the SQL way :)